# How to replace http:// or www with <a href.. in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've created this regex

```
(www|http://)[^ ]+
```

that match every *http://...* or *www....* but I dont know how to make preg_replace that would work, I've tried

```
preg_replace('/((www|http://)[^ ]+)/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $str);
```

but it doesn't work, the result is empty string.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507436/how-do-i-linkify-urls-in-a-string-with-php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to escape the slashes in the regex because you are using slashes as the delimiter. You could also use another symbol as the delimiter.

```
// escaped
preg_replace('/((www|http:\/\/)[^ ]+)/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $str);

// another delimiter, '@'
preg_replace('@((www|http://)[^ ]+)@', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $str);
```

Comment: Congrats! You’re the only one who doesn’t copy the incorrect regex from chaos.

Comment: It doesn't automatically add http:// before www so it's not entirely right: www.google.com will become <a href="www.google.com"> ... instead of <a href="http:// www.google.com">

Comment: not working when on the end of url is <br  so itch add br into url

Comment: At least can you fix your code?? It is not handling https or anything.. -.-

Comment: preg_replace('/((www|http:\/\/)[^,\\n ]+)/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $str);

just do little modification to stop replace when encounter  "," , "line feed"

Answer (score 2):

When using the regex codes provided by the other users, be sure to add the "i" flag to enable case-insensitivity, so it'll work with both HTTP:// and http://. For example, using chaos's code:

```
preg_replace('!(www|http://[^ ]+)!i', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to escape—or even better, replace—the delimeters as explained in the other answers.

```
preg_replace('~((www|http://)[^ ]+)~', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $str);
```

Secondly, to further improve the regex, the `$n` replacement reference syntax is preferred over `\\n`, as stated in the [manual](http://php.net/preg_replace).

```
preg_replace('~((www|http://)[^ ]+)~', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

Thirdly, you are needlessly using capturing parentheses, which only slows things down. Get rid of them. Don't forget to update `$1` to `$0`. In case you are wondering, these are non-capturing parentheses: `(?: )`.

```
preg_replace('~(?:www|http://)[^ ]+~', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $str);
```

Finally, I would replace `[^ ]+` with the shorter and more accurate `\S`, which is the opposite of `\s`. Note that `[^ ]+` does not allow spaces, but accepts newlines and tabs! `\S` does not.

```
preg_replace('~(?:www|http://)\S+~', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('!((?:www|http://)[^ ]+)!', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $str);
```

When you use `/` as your pattern delimiter, having `/` inside your pattern will not work out well.  I solved this by using `!` as the pattern delimiter, but you could escape your slashes with backslashes instead.

I also didn't see any reason why you were doing two paren captures, so I removed one of them.

Part of the trouble in your situation is that you're running with warnings suppressed; if you had `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on, you'd have seen the messages PHP is trying to generate about your delimiter problem in your regex.

Comment: Funny that most used your incorrect regex for their examples.

Comment: I imagine we were all copying OP's.  Fixed now, in any event.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem seems to be that you are putting everything in parentheses, so it doesn't know what "\1" is. Also, you need to escape the "/". So try this:

`preg_replace('/(www|http:\/\/[^ ]+)/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $str);`

Edit: It actually seems the parentheses were not an issue, I misread it. The escaping was still an issue as others also pointed out. Either solution should work.

Comment: I'd just like to add that back references are numbered by the opening parenthesis. For example, in the regexp "T(e(st))", \1 contains "est", and \2 contains "st".

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple url contained in a string a separated by a line break instead of a space, you have to use the \S

```
preg_replace('/((www|http:\/\/)\S+)/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $val);
```