# Auto-link URLs in a string

Tags: php, html

I have a normal message output $msg. I want it to make it links, if it is links. (containing http:// or www.) then it should make it `<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">http://google.com</a>`

I have stripped html from the messages

```
$msg = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($show["status"]), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')
```

How can that be done, seen it many places.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I linkify urls in a string with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507436/how-do-i-linkify-urls-in-a-string-with-php)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem like @SublymeRick (stops after first dot, see [Auto-link URLs in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144837/auto-link-urls-in-a-string#comment21280696_4144954)).

With a little inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218223/593957 I changed it to

```php
$msg = preg_replace('/((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression for this, via PHP's `preg_replace()` function.

Something like this....

```
preg_replace('/\b(https?:\/\/(.+?))\b/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $text);
```

Explaination:

Looks for `(https?://(.+?))` surrounded by `\b`, which is a beginning-of-word / end-of-word marker.

`https?://` is obvious (the `s?` means that the 's' is optional).

`(.+?)` means any number of any characters: 'any character' is represented by the dot; 'any number of' is the plus sign. The question mark means it isn't greedy, so it will allow the item after it (ie the `\b` end of word) to match at the first opportunity. This stops it just carrying on till the end of the string.

The whole expression is in brackets so that it gets picked up the the replacement system and can be re-inserted using `\1` in the second parameter.

Comment: Wouldn't you need 2 regexes, one for URLs with scheme and one for those without. Or you could use the `e` modifier and handle that case programmatically. (+ you need to escape the two forward slashes in your regex)

Comment: I tried using this expression and it stops after the first dot instead of completing the url.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
 preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code h    function AutoLinkUrls($str,$popup = FALSE){
    if (preg_match_all("#(^|\s|\()((http(s?)://)|(www\.))(\w+[^\s\)\<]+)#i", $str, $matches)){
        $pop = ($popup == TRUE) ? " target=\"_blank\" " : "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches['0']); $i++){
            $period = '';
            if (preg_match("|\.$|", $matches['6'][$i])){
                $period = '.';
                $matches['6'][$i] = substr($matches['6'][$i], 0, -1);
            }
            $str = str_replace($matches['0'][$i],
                    $matches['1'][$i].'<a href="http'.
                    $matches['4'][$i].'://'.
                    $matches['5'][$i].
                    $matches['6'][$i].'"'.$pop.'>http'.
                    $matches['4'][$i].'://'.
                    $matches['5'][$i].
                    $matches['6'][$i].'</a>'.
                    $period, $str);
        }//end for
    }//end if
    return $str;
}//end AutoLinkUrlsere
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue