# To validate url in jquery using regex

Tags: jquery, regex

Hi i want to validate url in jquery so i am using that regex expression

```
if(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(url)){
} else {
   $('#peUrl-'+index).prev('.errorHint').text("Please enter valid URL");    
}
```

But that regex expression is sometimes not working what is that issue in expression?

Comment: What URLs are failing?

Comment: Perhaps your regex is not complex enough. See https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: https://www.google.co.in

Comment: Because there is no protocol for that URL and your regex appears to require one

Comment: I provide url with protocal https in above url

Comment: see matthew's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url & also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188645/javascript-regex-to-match-a-url-in-a-field-of-text