# How to convert a link in a textarea into a link-element using php?

Tags: php, html, string

I was creating a script and it includes a posting script but I want users to directly copy a link from anywhere else and when they post it the link text should automatically convert the link to link-element (`<a>`).

So for example this:

```html
Ask this on http://stackoverflow.com now
```

to become

```html
Ask this on <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a> now
```

I have tried the `str_replace()` function but it wasn't the solution.

Can anyone tell me a solution to this?

Comment: You need to process the submitted string to check (regex) it is a valid url.After that you can just return an <a> tag with that string as href attribute <a href="[here the string]">link</a>

Comment: Is everything entered into text-box a link, or is it mixed data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I linkify urls in a string with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507436/how-do-i-linkify-urls-in-a-string-with-php)

Comment: Thanks Frank Farmer, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several solutions out there for this, most of them being poorly written and incomplete. In this situation I would advise to use an already existing solution of one of the big frameworks, there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

For example, [this article on Zenverse](http://zenverse.net/php-function-to-auto-convert-url-into-hyperlink/) describes the way [WordPress](http://www.wordpress.org/) handles this.

Let me add the snippet here for further reference:

```
function _make_url_clickable_cb($matches) {
    $ret = '';
    $url = $matches[2];

    if ( empty($url) )
        return $matches[0];
    // removed trailing [.,;:] from URL
    if ( in_array(substr($url, -1), array('.', ',', ';', ':')) === true ) {
        $ret = substr($url, -1);
        $url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url)-1);
    }
    return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"$url\" rel=\"nofollow\">$url</a>" . $ret;
}

function _make_web_ftp_clickable_cb($matches) {
    $ret = '';
    $dest = $matches[2];
    $dest = 'http://' . $dest;

    if ( empty($dest) )
        return $matches[0];
    // removed trailing [,;:] from URL
    if ( in_array(substr($dest, -1), array('.', ',', ';', ':')) === true ) {
        $ret = substr($dest, -1);
        $dest = substr($dest, 0, strlen($dest)-1);
    }
    return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"$dest\" rel=\"nofollow\">$dest</a>" . $ret;
}

function _make_email_clickable_cb($matches) {
    $email = $matches[2] . '@' . $matches[3];
    return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"mailto:$email\">$email</a>";
}

function make_clickable($ret) {
    $ret = ' ' . $ret;
    // in testing, using arrays here was found to be faster
    $ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])([\w]+?://[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is', '_make_url_clickable_cb', $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])((www|ftp)\.[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is', '_make_web_ftp_clickable_cb', $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])([.0-9a-z_+-]+)@(([0-9a-z-]+\.)+[0-9a-z]{2,})#i', '_make_email_clickable_cb', $ret);

    // this one is not in an array because we need it to run last, for cleanup of accidental links within links
    $ret = preg_replace("#(<a( [^>]+?>|>))<a [^>]+?>([^>]+?)</a></a>#i", "$1$3</a>", $ret);
    $ret = trim($ret);
    return $ret;
}
```

An example usage as written in the linked article:

```
$string = 'I have some texts here and also links such as http://www.youtube.com , www.haha.com and lol@example.com. They are ready to be replaced.';

echo make_clickable($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is first to find substrings that are links. For that, you could use regexps. Then, you need to add html tags around the link. [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) should be your friend.

For example (simplified example):

```
$linkedtext = preg_replace ( '@\bhttp://([a-zA-Z0-9.%/]+)\b@', '<a href="http://$1">$1</a>', $text)
```

For better url matching regex, see [Regex to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)