# Linkify URLs with PHP, trim outputted urls length

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to automatically format text to links in PHP but to trim long urls to a max character limit. And also remove 'http(s)' from outputted text.

`blah blah http://example.com/some-long-slug-goes-here foo`

should translate to:

`blah blah <a href="http://example.com/some-long-slug-goes-here">example.com/some-long-sl...</a> foo` (*blah blah [**example.com/some-long-sl...**](http://example.com/some-long-slug-goes-here) foo*)

Found a `preg_replace` solution here: [How do I linkify urls in a string with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/507436/107671) but I'm incapable of editing it to my needs.

```
$string = preg_replace(
  "~[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]~",
  "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", 
  $string
);
```

Comment: As @chris85 mentioned, and use this as replacement `<a href="\0">\1</a>` (escaped obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a capture group after the protocol:

```
$string = preg_replace(
  "~[[:alpha:]]+://([^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/])~",
  "<a href=\"\\0\">\\1</a>", 
  $string
);
```

then `\1` will be the URL without the protocol. For the text limiting I'd recommend using CSS, [Setting a max character length in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973570/setting-a-max-character-length-in-css).

Comment: Thank you, this fixes it! :) Would it be possible to also remove the 'www.'?

Comment: Yes, put the `www.` after the protocol but before the capture group, you also  probably want that optional.. so update the beginning to `[[:alpha:]]+://(?:www\.)?`